# EOF vs basic_ios::eof() on GCC 5.2.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, ifstream

On a program compiled with GCC 5.2.1, the state of `ifstream` doesn't switch to `basic_ios::eof()` when it hits the end of a file—namely, the condition `if(eof())` evaluates to `false` after the end of file has been reached—whereas the same code compiled on Visual Studio 2015 behaves as expected: when the end of file is reached, the `basic_ios::eof()` evaluates to `true` in the `if` conditional.

I substituted the `if(eof())` with `if(bad())` and then with `if(fail())`, and all of them evaluated to `false`. However, when I place the `EOF` macro instead, the `if(EOF)` evaluates to `true`―just like the `if(eof())` does on the program compiled by VS.

What may be the reason for `std::basic_ios::eof()` not to work on a program compiled with GCC?

PS: Below is the code of the program

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int ex10()
{
    ifstream in{ "school.txt" };
    if (!in) cout << "The 'school.txt' file was not opened.\n";

    string line;

    regex header{ R"(^([\w]+)(\t{2}\w+\s*\w*)(\t\w+\s*\w*)(\t\w+\s*\w*)$)" };
    regex row{ R"(^(\w+\s*\w*)(\t{1,2}\d+)(\t{2}\d+)(\t{2}\d+)$)" };

    if (getline(in, line)) {
        smatch matches;
        if (!regex_match(line, matches, header))
            cerr << "Wrong header format.\n";
    }
    int linenum = 0;
    int boys = 0;
    int girls = 0;

    ofstream out{ "schoolCompressed.txt" };
    if (!out) cout << "The output file was not created.\n";
    string prevLine;
    int accumBoys;
    int accumGirls;
    int accumTot;

    while (getline(in, line)) {
        ++linenum;
        smatch matches;
        if (!regex_match(line, matches, row))
            cerr << "Row #" << linenum << " doesn't match the format.\n";


        int curr_boy = stoi(matches[2]);
        int curr_girl = stoi(matches[3]);
        int curr_total = stoi(matches[4]);

        if (curr_boy + curr_girl != curr_total)
            cerr << "Wrong children number in line #" << linenum << '\n';

        if (line[0] != prevLine[0]) {

            if (linenum != 1) out << prevLine[0] << "\t\t" << accumBoys << "\t\t"
                << accumGirls << "\t\t" << accumTot << '\n';
            accumBoys = curr_boy;
            accumGirls = curr_girl;
            accumTot = curr_total;

        }

        else if (line[0] == prevLine[0]) {

            accumBoys += curr_boy;
            accumGirls += curr_girl;
            accumTot += curr_total;
        }


        if (EOF && curr_boy == boys && curr_girl == girls) { out << line; return 0; } //this works on GCC
        //if (in.eof() && curr_boy == boys && curr_girl == girls) { out << line; return 0; } <= this works on VS 2015


        boys += curr_boy;
        girls += curr_girl;
        prevLine = line;
    }
    cerr << "Somehow the program didn't manage to complete its task :(.\n";
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    ex10();
}
```

Text of the `school.txt` file

`KLASSE      DRENGE  PIGER   ELEVER
0A              12      11      23
1A              7       8       15
1B              4       11      15
2A              10      13      23
3A              10      12      22
4A              7       7       14
4B              10      5       15
5A              19      8       27
6A              10      9       19
6B              9       10      19
7A              7       19      26
7G              3       5       8
7I              7       3       10
8A              10      16      26
9A              12      15      27
0MO             3       2       5
0P1             1       1       2
0P2             0       5       5
10B             4       4       8
10CE            0       1       1
1MO             8       5       13
2CE             8       5       13
3DCE            3       3       6
4MO             4       1       5
6CE             3       4       7
8CE             4       4       8
9CE             4       9       13
REST            5       6       11
Alle klasser    184     202     386`

Comment: We can't tell why your program doesn't work without actually seeing your program. Please post an [mcve] containing everything we would need to reproduce the problem.

Comment: if (EOF)? really ? EOF is a constant.

Comment: @UmNyobe in fact, when if there is only `if (curr_boy == boys && curr_girl == girls)` without `eof()` or `EOF` the code compiles and works. I just don't understand why `eof()` doesn't work when the code is compiled on GCC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EOF is a macro for a constant integer so it is not surprise that

```
 if (EOF && curr_boy == boys && curr_girl == girls)
```

is "working". It is just not doing what you expect, which is checking end of file.

You should use `eof()` only when an io operation has failed. 
The [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) stipulates that

> std::basic_ios::eof only reports the stream state as set by the most
>   recent I/O operation.it does not examine the associated data source. For example, if the most recent I/O was a get(), which returned the last byte of a file, **eof() returns false**. The ***next*** get() fails to read anything and sets the eofbit. Only then eof() returns true

In your code you have

```
while (getline(in, line)) {
   ...
   if (in.eof())
   ...
}
```

The expected behavior is the one of GCC. To know that you are at the end of the file you should attempt to read further. This is a similar issue to

```
while (!in.eof()) {
   ...
   getline(in, line)
   ...
}
```

What you should is move curr_boy and the condition out of the while loop and eliminate the eof test

```
int curr_boy = 0;
int curr_girl = 0;
while (getline(in, line)) {
}

if (curr_boy == boys && curr_girl == girls) { out << line; return 0; }
```

Comment: but wouldn't the `if (curr_boy == boys && curr_girl == girls)` produce an error—because the variables `curr_boy` and `curr_girl` were declared inside it.
When I placed it outside the loop, as you advised, and modified to `if(in.eof()) { out << prevLine; return 0; }` it worked. But now I am even more befuddled: How come the Visual Studio made the code work properly on Windows?!

Comment: It wasnt clear but yeah you have to move the curr variables outside. The loop terminate most of the time when there is eof. but you have to execute the getline which will cause the eof. That's why eof work outside of the loop and should not work inside. Now Visual studio is known for not being strictly conformance to the standard. It may be a bug in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same file with the same OS?

The `getline` function will set the `eof` flag if it hits the end of the file before seeing a `'\n'`. This can only happen on the very last line of a file.

You should probably move your end test to *outside* the while-loop, where we know that we have hit the end of the file when the latest `getline` failed to read another line.

Comment: the `school.txt` file is the same in both cases. The last line of the table doesn't end with '\n'.

Comment: That's why I asked about the operating systems. If you run under Cygwin, for example, there is a configuration to select Windows or Linux rules for line endings in text files. That could make a difference. Anyway, why not just read until there are no more lines, then you know you're at the end.

Comment: I use the GCC-compiled executable on Ubuntu 15; the VS-compiled one I use on Windows 7. The one which is on Windows doesn't have that problem.